# Auto generating unique ID in Power apps and Microsoft Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, office365-apps, powerapps-formula, microsoft-forms

I am tasked in developing a form which is going to record and store data into a SharePoint list (Office 365 online SharePoint) So far I have been looking into two different methods I am not sure if they are suitable given the requirements of the work scope. The requirement is that each form has to be assigned to a unique ID/serial number and the data in the form has to be passed to a SharePoint list.

The first method that I have looked at is using Microsoft Forms to be the online form to collect the data and Power Automate to get the data and put it into a SharePoint list. The problem is I do not know if there is a way to assign a unique ID on the form itself before submitting the form. Is there a way or method where I can autogenerate a unique ID/serial number on a form before submitting it ?

I am also looking at using PowerApps to create a form which will be linked to the SharePoint list. Is there a way to autogenerate a unique ID/serial number and prepopulate it on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The most flexible, customizable solution would be PowerApps**

PowerApps will connect directly to Sharepoint as a data source. There is most definitely a way to autogenerate a unique ID/serial number in PowerApps. Look into the [`GUID()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-guid).

**Some great use cases for Microsoft Forms include:**

- External users (those outside your Active Directory tenant) need to fill in data
- The form is dead simple (few questions, minimal logic, etc.)

Each Microsoft Form submitted also has an *ID* (`Response ID`)...
[image]

But it is not suitable as a GUID/serial number. You could add one in Power Automate, using the [`guid()` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#guid) before creating the record in Sharepoint:
[image]

The entire workflow ends up looking like this:
[image]